# Create JSON nested output from two different Django Models

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am a newbie to django-rest-framework and I would like to create a JSON output from by combining two different models data like the input JSON I supply.

The models are as below:

Banks

```
class Banks(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    bank_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    min_amount = models.FloatField(max_length=255, null=False
```

Rates

```
class Rates(models.Model):
    term = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    band = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    rate = models.FloatField(null=True)
    bank = models.ForeignKey(Banks, related_name='rates', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

Basically the idea is that banks can have multiple rates for different periods.

I created a serializer which allowed me to POST in a nested JSON and it loaded the bank data and rate data properly. Serializer classes as below:

```
class RatesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Rates
        fields = ("id", "term", "band", "rate", "bank")


class BanksSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rates = RatesSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Banks
        fields = ("id", "country", "bank_name", "rates", "min_amount")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        rates_data = validated_data.pop('rates')
        bank = Banks.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for rate_data in rates_data:
            Rates.objects.create(bank=bank, **rate_data)
        return bank
```

However I am stuck and do not know how to retrieve say banks and their rates for a specific country.

I am posting the following:

```
{
    "country": "CN",
    "bank_name": "CNBC",
    "rates": [
        {"term":1, "band":"0-10000", "rate":0.025},
        {"term":1, "band":"10000-50000", "rate":0.03},
        {"term":1, "band":"50000-100000", "rate":0.035},
        {"term":1, "band":"100000-250000", "rate":0.04},
        {"term":1, "band":"250000-500000", "rate":0.05},
        {"term":1, "band":"500000-1000000", "rate":0.06},
        {"term":1, "band":">1000000", "rate":0.06}
    ],
    "min_amount": 10000
}
```

When I want to use a view set to retrieve the data I attempted the following but the data does not get joined in anyway. How could I return the same JSON above with a list of banks and their rates filtered by country?

I attempted the following:

```
banks = Banks.objects.filter(country=country).values()
rates = Rates.objects.get(bank_in=banks).values()
```

But that does not return the list of the banks with the rates. Just the list of banks separate from rates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined Serializer but why dont you use it?

```py
banks = Banks.objects.filter(country=country)
serializer = BanksSerializer(banks, many=True)
serializer.data
```

Comment: This is definitely the solution thanks! Didn't know I could do that.